# Does anyone know which database table Job Titles are stored in on WSS 3.0?

Tags: wss-3.0, database

I need to edit the job titles of users in an installation of WSS 3.0. There doesn't seem to be an easy way of doing this as an administrator. Users can edit their own details via the _layouts/useredit.aspx link. But I need to do the update for all users myself.

I was thinking of doing a global update by writing a SQL script to update the relevant fields in the DB.

I can access the WSS database tables via SQL Server Management Studio Express. There is a table named dbo.UserInfo which seems to hold the users details (Name, Email) but this doesn't hold the Job Title info.

Does anyone know where in the DB the Job Titles are stored? Or how I can go about updating the Job Titles another way?

Thanks in advance.
Nigel

Comment: Can you not update them in active directory?

Answer (score 1):

The information is stored in a list called "User Information List" at the RootWeb of each SPSite.

This is "almost" an ordinary SharePoint list so you can:

```
Loop throught all WebApplications  
  For each loop through all SPSites 
    For each take the RootWeb
    Get the rootweb.Lists["User Information List"]
    Loop through all SPListItems
      Foreach Update item["JobTitle"]
      Call item.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

They're stored in the UserInfo table of each Content Database, however modifying the database directly in SharePoint puts your farm in an "unsupported state".

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what the column is called as I can't find them? Aware that this would put the farm in unsupported state but can't find anyway of doing this otherwise. Unless people have any suggestions? Can't wait til we upgrade to SP2010!